# Count no. of text fields & show the total no in another page

Tags: javascript, php

**search.php**

```
<?php
$serial_no = 1;
$total_seats = $_SESSION['total_seats'];
$seats = explode(',', rtrim($total_seats, ","));
foreach ($seats as $seat) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $serial_no++; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $seat; ?> </td> </tr>
```

**view.php**

```
<td>Total seats</td>
<td> : </td>    
<td> </td>
```

Here in view.php page in the `<td>` , i want to show the total no of seats displayed in search.php page.. i mean when there are 4 text fields displayed in search.php page, i want to show in the view.php page,  total seats : 4

Comment: i just want to count the no of array

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ,

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $total_seats = $_SESSION['total_seats'];
    $seats = explode(',', rtrim($total_seats, ","));
    $totalCount=count($seats);
?>
```

Where `count` is the inbuilt function returning the length of the array element.

Comment: Do you have the values in the `$_SESSION['total_seats]`?. If it is not there it would have caused the error

Comment: yeah i think .. i ll ve to call my session perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the same code you use in search.php, just with the function `count()` added to count the array elements.
Try this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['total_seats'])){
        $total_seats = $_SESSION['total_seats'];
        $seats = explode(',', rtrim($total_seats, ","));
    }
?>
<tr>
    <td>Total seats: <?php echo count($seats); ?></td>
</tr>
```

This will work provided your `$_SESSION['total_seats']` does not change mid-way.

Comment: undefined index erro.. i think i should use session here

Comment: $_SESSION['total_seats'] is not available in my view page.. so its giving me the undefined index error

Comment: Is it unavailable in **search.php** too?

Comment: i ve already started my session in the beginiing, its again giving me undefined variable :(

Comment: $count = count($_SESSION['total_seats']); 

i used this code,  it's only giving me the result 1...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...this code will help in your work.

**search.php**

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="total_seats" />
<input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['search'])){
$serial_no = 1;
$total_seats = $_POST['total_seats'];

$seats = explode(',', rtrim($total_seats, ","));
//echo "<pre>";print_r($seats);die;
?>
<table>
<?php foreach ($seats as $seat) { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $serial_no; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $seat; ?> </td> 
</tr>
<?php $serial_no++; 
}
$serial_no--;
session_start();
$_SESSION['seats'] = $serial_no;
header("Location:view.php");
?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

**view.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "Hello " . $_SESSION['seats'];
```

Comment: i know this .. but i just want to count the no of array in my search.php page and display the no in view page

Comment: okay, you can count array and store in your session then display in view.php. EX: $count = count($seats);
$_SESSION['seats'] = $count;

Comment: wohi undefined index error.. there is problm in my session may be, i think i m not calling it properly

Comment: $count = count($_SESSION['total_seats']); 

i used this code,  it's only giving me the result 1...

Comment: don't count the session var dear. count the array then hold the value in the session.

Comment: i was off for some days, so trying again, it's giving me either 1 or error @the clouds